# Group by name, count and total, and display it in a view using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, struct

I thought I wasn't a rookie anymore, until I stumbled upon this.

I'm trying to load an html list, grouping shops per user and displaying per shop, the number of receipts and total amount.

In Sql I would do this easily with a group by, so I was trying to load the code below, within my Shop Model, into my Rails Console.

```
 def self.group_receipts(user, search_hash=nil)

    shop_ids = Shop.pluck(:id) & Receipt.from_companies(user, search_hash).pluck(:shop_id)

    #greceipt means Grouped Receipt
    greceipt = Struct.new(:name, :number_of_receipts, :total)

    query = Shop.joins(:receipts).where('shops.id in (?)',shop_ids).select('shops.name,count(receipts.id) as number_of_receipts,sum(receipts.total) as total').group('shops.id')

    query

  end
```

Here is my output

```
>> Shop.group_receipts(302).all
   (2.0ms)  SELECT id FROM "shops" 
   (3.0ms)  SELECT shop_id FROM "receipts" WHERE (receipts.id IN (SELECT receipts.id
 FROM receipts
 INNER JOIN shops on shops.id=receipts.shop_id
 INNER JOIN companies on companies.id = shops.company_id
 INNER JOIN user_companies on user_companies.company_id = companies.id
 WHERE user_companies.user_id = 302)) AND (receipts.is_manual is null or receipts.is_manual=false) ORDER BY receipts.created_at DESC
  Shop Load (2.0ms)  SELECT shops.name,count(receipts.id) as number_of_receipts,sum(receipts.total) as total FROM "shops" INNER JOIN "receipts" ON "receipts"."shop_id" = "shops"."id" WHERE (shops.id in (16)) GROUP BY shops.id
[#<Shop name: "Kirlin Osinski and Dooley">]
```

If my query seems to be all right, why is that that my output is not something like `name, 10, 1000` ?

That greceipt struct you find on the method definition intends to create a structure so that, we can later access gs.name, gs.number_of_receipts, gs.total, but i cannot understand how to load a list of objects of this struct type from the output presented above :-S.

Anyone to the rescue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of this [forum](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3073356), I understood that the problem was within rails console.

I ended up with

model:

```
def self.group_receipts(user, search_hash=nil)

    shop_ids = Shop.pluck(:id) & Receipt.from_companies(user, search_hash).pluck(:shop_id)
    query = Shop.joins(:receipts).where('shops.id in (?)',shop_ids).select('shops.name,count(receipts.id) as number_of_receipts,sum(receipts.total) as total').group('shops.id')
    query

end
```

controller:

```
@receipts_per_shop = Shop.group_receipts(current_user)
```

partial view _receipts_per_shop:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
  <th><%=t 'activerecord.attributes.shop.name'%></th>
  <th>#</th>
  <th>Total</th>
  </thead>
  <% if @shops.present? %>
      <%= render partial: '/shops/receipt_per_shop', collection: @receipts_per_shop %>
  <% else %>
      <tbody><tr><td colspan="3"><%= t('no_records') %></td></tr></tbody>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

partial view _receipt_per_shop

```
<% @receipts_per_shop.each do |rs| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= rs.name %></td>
      <td><%= rs.number_of_receipts %></td>
      <td><%= rs.total %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```